# How to copy one big file to two drives C: and D:?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

As total space including (C: and D: drives) availalbe in my PC is around 4GB.
But `C` is having 2GB and `D` is having 2GB then how to copy a file of size 3GB.

Please don't say that to merge both drives, I don't want to do that.

Any solution is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not `split` the file in two?

Comment: if free space on system drive is only 2GB then you're running into some problem. Try freeing some more space by various ways like disabling hibernate file, cleaning system (with a program that can do deep cleaning like ccleaner, not windows cleaner), reducing pagefile size or move it to some other place, applying compressed properties on NTFS folders (not compressing them), removing old windows backups and updates, recoveries... For copying the file, splitting it by a tool like 7z, winrar, file splitter...

Comment: Buy a bigger drive - really. 2GB spare on any drive is going to leave it struggling to breathe, it will be fragmented to death & it's a wonder it manages to start up in less than 10 minutes in a morning

Comment: You can split the file into parts with software like 7zip, then plugin Flashdrive/pendrive into USB port, set this pendrive as a temporary directory in 7zip, move files to D drive, use 7zip to decompress files and tick the checkmark to delete after decompression.